# How to add all images from a folder to a button (in my frame)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to store `.jpg` images from a folder in an array, and than use them to add it  to a buttons in my frame of Python.

I am using tkinter and PIL library in Python 3.4.3 .I am using windows 8.1 os I want to load the image for a folder with few lines of code and I also element border of the grid to show them like a single image

Comment: You need to put some more detail into your question! It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do. And you need to tell us which GUI library and which version of Python you're using. You're more likely to get help on SO if you post a [MCVE] that shows what you've tried.

Comment: I want my frame to have lot of image button . which connect to other frames.

Comment: You should edit that info into your question. But it's not clear what you mean by "connect to other frames". And we can't help you much if you don't tell us which GUI system you're using. Are you using tkinter, gtk, pyqt, or something else? If you don't clarify your question, preferably including some code, it risks being put on hold until you fix it up.

Comment: I figured you were using `tkinter` (Python 2: `Tkinter` by the language of the question. But I'm having difficulty understanding "use them to add it to a buttons in my frame of Python". Since there's no code, this is all happening in our imaginations, which is why the guidelines suggest you provide broken code. Take a stab at it, then say what you aren't understanding!

Comment: I _could_ show you how to make a grid of Tkinter Buttons containing images from a named folder. But I can't tell from your question if that's what you want.

Comment: I want to load the image for a folder with few lines of code and I also element border of the grid to show them like a singe image

Comment: What part of the problem are you struggling with? Do you know how to create a window? Do you know how to add a label with an image? Do you know how to read a directory to get a list of files? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

Below is some code to get you started.

To simplify testing I wrote a small program that uses PIL to generate colored squares and saves them to a folder. I tested these programs using Python 2.6.6 on Linux. They should work on Python 3, (assuming Tkinter & PIL are installed properly on your system) but you will need to change `import Tkinter as tk` to
`import tkinter as tk` in tk_frame_grid.py.

---

This program generates 30 colored squares, saving them to the 'squares' folder in the current directory. You need to create 'squares' before running the program.

**PIL_2colorsquares.py**

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Create squares that fade from one color to another & save

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.07.18
'''

from PIL import Image
from itertools import permutations

def color_squares(size, colorpairs, basename, ftype):
    #Make the composition mask
    m = 255.0 / (2 * size - 2)
    r = range(size)
    mask = Image.new('L', (size, size))
    mask.putdata([int(m * (x + y)) for y in r for x in r])

    for count, (c0, c1) in enumerate(colorpairs):
        im0 = Image.new('RGB', (size, size), color=c0)
        im1 = Image.new('RGB', (size, size), color=c1)
        im = Image.composite(im0, im1, mask)
        im.save('%s%03d%s' % (basename, count, ftype))


def main():
    size = 64
    colors = ('red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'magenta')
    colorpairs = permutations(colors, 2)
    basename = 'squares/sq'
    ftype = '.png'
    color_squares(size, colorpairs, basename, ftype)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

This program first fills a list with PIL images, using image files from a named directory; these images can be in any file format that PIL can read. It then creates a Tkinter window containing a Frame that holds a grid of Buttons using the images. There is no error checking, so don't put non-image files into the 'squares' folder.

You need to specify the grid dimensions. If there aren't enough images to fill the grid you will get a `StopIteration` error.

**tk_frame_grid.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Create a grid of Tkinter Buttons with PIL images in a Frame

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31489121/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.07.18
'''

from __future__ import print_function

import os
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class FrameDemo(object):
    ''' A Frame containing a grid of image Buttons '''
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, images):
        images = iter(images)

        master = tk.Tk()
        master.title("Image Buttons in a Frame")

        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        for y in range(rows):
            for x in range(columns):
                #Get the next image from the list and
                #convert it to a TK Photo object
                name, img = next(images)
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

                #Create the button & put it in the Frame
                b = tk.Button(frame, image=photo)
                b.grid(row=y, column=x)

                #Add a call-back function
                func = lambda t=name: self.button_cb(t)
                b.config(command=func)

                #We have to save a reference to the photo or it gets
                #garbage-collected, so we attach it as a button attribute
                b.photo = photo

        master.mainloop()

    def button_cb(self, name):
        print("'%s' button pressed" % name)


def main():
    image_folder = 'squares'
    #Load all files in image_folder as PIL images
    #and put them into a list
    images = [(name, Image.open(os.path.join(image_folder, name)))
        for name in sorted(os.listdir(image_folder))]
    gui = FrameDemo(rows=5, columns=6, images=images)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```