# Python Tkinter PhotoImage file formats supported?

Tags: python, tkinter

I appreciate this is a VERY novice question but I just want to check in regard to Tkinter Photoimage class, is it only GIF/PGM/PPM images that it can read from files and nothing else unless I download the Python Image Library.

If thats the case I now know exactly where I went wrong in the code I'm writing. IE: wrong file format

Comment: Well, that's what [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) say. But it's very easy to read other formats using [ImageTk.PhotoImage](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) from PIL/Pillow - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498692/4014959) for an example that uses PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds right.  There may be another format or two that native Tkinter supports, but it's very limited.  There's a more up-to-date version of PIL named Pillow that you might want to look into.  It doesn't seem like PIL is being actively maintained, last I looked.  If you want to work with JPEG for example, you need PIL (or Pillow).