# Python change gradient to start diagonally

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-imaging-library

I have a simple function that generates gradient. I would like to change the direction of the gradient to start **diagonally top left**.

```
im = Image.new('RGB', (300, 300))
ld = im.load()

# A map of rgb points in your distribution
# [distance, (r, g, b)]
# distance is percentage from left edge
heatmap = [

    [0.0, (0, 0, 0)],
    [1.00, (0.8, 0.0, 1.0)],
]


def gaussian(x, a, b, c, d=0):
    return a * math.exp(-(x - b) ** 2 / (2 * c ** 2)) + d


def pixel(x, width=100, map=[], spread=1):
    width = float(width)
    r = sum([gaussian(x, p[1][0], p[0] * width, width / (spread * len(map))) for p in map])
    g = sum([gaussian(x, p[1][1], p[0] * width, width / (spread * len(map))) for p in map])
    b = sum([gaussian(x, p[1][2], p[0] * width, width / (spread * len(map))) for p in map])
    return min(1.0, r), min(1.0, g), min(1.0, b)


for x in range(im.size[0]):
    r, g, b = pixel(x, width=300, map=heatmap)
    r, g, b = [int(256 * v) for v in (r, g, b)]
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        ld[x, y] = r, g, b
```

I have found I can change the direction top to bottom and left to right but don't know how to change it diagonally.

```
for y in range(im.size[1]):
    ld[y, x] = r, g, b
```

Gives...

[image]

```
for y in range(im.size[1]):
    ld[x, y] = r, g, b
```

Gives...

[image]

Is this possible using the current functions and how?

Comment: You _may_ find the first program in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498692/4014959) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
heatmap = [

    [0.0, (0, 0, 0)],
    [1.00, (0.8, 0.0, 1.0)],
]

# x y coordinates of starting point for gradient
start_x = 0
start_y = 0

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        # taxicab distance for linear gradient 
        dist = math.fabs(start_x - x) + math.fabs(start_y - y)
        # for circular gradient
        # dist = math.sqrt(math.pow(start_x - x,2) + math.pow(start_y - y,2))
        start_rgb = heatmap[0][1]
        end_rgb = heatmap[1][1]
        dist = dist / (im.size[0] + im.size[1])
        # for circular gradient
        # dist = dist / (math.sqrt(math.pow(im.size[0],2) + math.pow(im.size[1],2)) 
        r, g, b = map(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda a: a*dist, start_rgb), map(lambda b: b*dist, end_rgb))
        r, g, b = [int(256 * v) for v in (r, g, b)]
        ld[x, y] = r, g, b
```

I have assumed that `start_x` and `start_y` is located on one of the four corners of the image. Adjust `start_x - x` and `start_y - y` accordingly if it is not .

Answer (score 1):

your `width` should be 300*300
then replacing your loop by the following one should work

```
for y in range(im.size[1]-1):
    r, g, b = pixel(y, width=300*300, map=heatmap)
    r, g, b = [int(256 * v) for v in (r, g, b)]
    for x_ in range(y+1):
        ld[x_,y - x_] = r, g, b

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    r, g, b = pixel(300+x, width=300*300, map=heatmap)
    r, g, b = [int(256 * v) for v in (r, g, b)]
    for y_ in range(im.size[1]):
        ld[x - y_,y_] = r, g, b
```

not tested but something like that should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it just in case anyone was doing it in pygame and was struggling

```
gradient = pygame.PixelArray(WIN)

start_rgb = (0, 0, 255)
end_rgb = (255, 20, 147)

for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        dist = x + y
        dist /= WIDTH + HEIGHT
        # Now dist will be a normalized value, between 0 and 1

        r, g, b = map(lambda start, end: start + end, map(lambda _a: max(0, _a - (255 * dist)), start_rgb), map(lambda _b: _b * dist, end_rgb))

        gradient[x][y] = r, g, b
```

I know that it's pretty much a copy of the first persons answer, but it took me 2 days to understand, so I decided to do this

First we make the gradient variable which has the color of every pixel in the window

Then we make the start_rgb and end_rgb variables

Then we loop through every pixel in the window and make the dist variable

We make the r, g and b variables and here we have three map functions:

`map(lambda _a: max(0, _a - (255 * dist)), start_rgb)`
Here we loop through every element in start_rgb and subtract 255(The max color value in pygame) * dist which will be 0 at the start and 1 at the end. And we use the max function so that if the number was less that zero it will be set to zero

`map(lambda _b: _b * dist, end_rgb)`
Here we loop through every element in end_rgb and multiply it by dist

`map(lambda start, end: start + end, map(...), map(...))`
Here we just add the results we got from the first map function I talked about and the second map function I talked about

Then, here: `gradient[x][y] = r, g, b` we set the pixel in x, y to the color we just calculated

and here is what you should get from this code [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8xwV.png)