# How to use an image array in tkinter?

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am creating a UI using tkinter. I am using images to improve the look of my buttons. This seems to be quite tedious and I was wondering if it was possible to create an array to make things easier.

I would like to make an image with multiple icons, all the same size. I also need a way to call the individual icons out from that main image, instead of saving and importing each individual image.

Is this possible? As of right now, I am just importing the images separately.

Comment: Yes, you can put images in an array. It is no different than putting integers or strings or anything else into an array. Your question is a bit too vague for stackoverflow. Why don't you try to create a program with a single button that has two or three images. Try putting the images in an array, and when you get stuck you can come back and ask a question.

Comment: Combining multiple images into one image file like that is often called "image sprites". You can read the image file and extract the individual sprites from the image using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/), and convert them to Tkinter form with `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. You might find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498692/4014959) helpful. It doesn't use image sprites, but it does show how to create a grid of Tkinter Buttons with PIL images in a Frame.