# Treat Label as image when not displaying an image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a `Label` that will *eventually* display an image, but when the program starts I just want it to be blank. However, I also need to set the `width` and `height` of the `Label` in order to make the layout look good.

Because `Label` treats `width` and `height` as number of lines/characters when the `image` attribute isn't set, things look very wrong.

So how can I make the `Label` behave as an image (pixel width/height) without actually setting an image?

Comment: You could put the Label into a Frame, as mentioned in the docs. Although the Label docs themselves don't give details, they do link to the Button docs, which _do_ have [example code](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#patterns). If you don't want to use a Frame you could just stick a blank image in there; a blank 2 colour PNG is only a handful of bytes.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using a blank image - can I easily create one programmatically or is it better to just create a 1x1 transparent PNG?

Comment: You could create one programmatically, eg using PIL, but it's probably simpler to just load one off disk. FWIW, here's some code I wrote a year ago that generates coloured squares in PIL and saves them to disk http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498692/4014959